# How to break up an ArrayList<String> by searching for a given character and creating new ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to break up an String ArrayList by searching each String for a given character. Separating the lists into new lists according to the common position of the character.

If the array is

```
list1 = new String[] {"fish", "look", "flow", "fowl", "cool"};
```

and the given character is 'l' then I would get 4 new arrays no l "----"(fish), "l---"(look), "-l--"(flow), "---l"(fowl, cool). The arraylists would have the corresponding strings in them. The error I get is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
ArrayList<String> ret = f.familiesOf('l');
        assertTrue(ret.contains("----"));


    public Family_2(String[] w)
    {
        words = w;
    }

    /**
     * Given a single character, return an ArrayList of
     * all the word families. Each family should
     * appear only once in the ArrayList and there should be none
     * that aren't needed. The returned list can be in any order.
     */

    public ArrayList<String> familiesOf(char c)
    {
        String fam = "";
        ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> wordList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        Collections.addAll(wordList, words);
        String longestString = wordList.get(0);

        // when I added the below code I stopped getting an out of bounds exception.

        for (String element : wordList)
        {
            if (element.length() > longestString.length()) {
                longestString = element;
            }
        }   

        // This is where I'm struggling with checking and separating the ArrayList.

        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
        {
            if(words[i].indexOf(c) != c)
            {
                fam += '-'; 
                wordList2 = wordList;
            }
            else if(words[i].indexOf(c) == c)
            {
                fam += c;
                wordList2 = wordList;
            }
        }
        return wordList;
    }
```

This is a precursor to a hangman game being created.

Comment: How to handle the case where the word contains more than one occurrence of the letter, e.g. `well`?

Comment: Is the list of words, i.e. `list1` in the code you posted, guaranteed not to have duplicate words?

Comment: What about case sensitivity? Are all the words lower-case only?

Comment: They will all have lower case words and occasionally duplicate letters. Like eel, poll, fill. They would have there own arraylist "--ll", "ee-" etc. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key to implementing your algorithm is choosing the correct data structure. I think the correct data structure would be a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). The `Map` key would be `Integer` (since the key cannot be a primitive, so it cannot be `int`) which would be the index of the letter, and the value would be a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of the words that have the relevant letter at that index.

Here is my code that implements the algorithm, according to the specifications and limitations you detailed.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class HangsMan {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] words = new String[]{"fish", "look", "flow", "fowl", "cool", "eel", "poll", "fill"};
        char letter = 'l';
        Map<Integer, List<String>> theMap = new HashMap<>();
        Integer key;
        List<String> value;
        for (String word : words) {
            int ndx = word.indexOf(letter);
            int last = word.lastIndexOf(letter);
            if (last == ndx + 1) {
                ndx += 1_000_000;
            }
            key = Integer.valueOf(ndx);
            if (theMap.containsKey(key)) {
                value = theMap.get(key);
            }
            else {
                value = new ArrayList<String>();
                theMap.put(key, value);
            }
            value.add(word);
        }
        theMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(v));
    }
}
```

Note that words with double letters have 1_000_000 (one million) added to the index so as to keep them separate from single letter words. Hence the index for the word *poll* would be 1,000,002 and the index for the word *cold* would be just 2.

Why do I add one million, you ask? Because, according to *Wikipedia*, the longest word in the English language contains [189,819](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_word_in_English) letters.